# Табулирование функции. Как правильно описать цикл разложения ряда функции ln((1+x)/(1-x)?

Tags: c++, циклы, математика, рекурсия, ряды

Есть функция с описанием члена ряда. И при в ходе в эту функцию, каждый член считается заново и аккамуляции ряда не идет. Приложу задание. Были перепробованы разные циклы, но ничего не помогает.

In ((1+x)/(1-x)) =2*(x+x^3/3+x^5/5 +⋯+x^(2m-1 )/(2m-1)+⋯),xϵ[-1;1]

Подобрать значения начального и конечного значения х, а также шага его изменения   исходя из  области определения математической функции и области сходимости ряда. Результатом работы программы должна быть таблица, состоящая из   столбцов. В первом должны находится значения аргумента, во втором – значение функции в данной точке х, в третьем – сумма значений ряда (без применения рекурсии), в четвертом - сумма значений ряда (с применением рекурсии), в пятом – количество вызовов рекурсивной функции. При построении таблицы необходимо использовать указатели на функции.  Завершать процесс суммирования членов ряда необходимо до момента когда разница между значением математической функции и  суммой членов её разложения меньше эпсилон (вводится с клавиатуры).
При наборе заданий возможны ошибки. В таких случаях производить вычисления до момента, когда n – ый член последовательности меньше эпсилон, или просто ограничить значение n.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    double LogFunction(double x);
double SumRows(double x, double Eps);




int main()
{
    double XStart, XFinish, DeltaX, X, Y, Result, Eps;
    double(*Logarifm)(double x);
    Logarifm = LogFunction;
    double(*RowTeylor)(double x, double Eps);
    RowTeylor = SumRows;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите начальное значение аргумента X на [-1;1]" << endl;
    cin >> XStart;
    cout << "Введите конечное значение аргумента X  на [-1;1]" << endl;
    cin >> XFinish;
    cout << "Введите значение приращения X" << endl;
    cin >> DeltaX;
    cout << "Введите значение погрешности Епсилон" << endl;
    cin >> Eps;
    X = XStart;
    while (X < XFinish + 1e-8)
    {
        Y = Logarifm(X);
        Result = RowTeylor(X, Eps);
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.precision(3);
        cout << X << "    " << Y << "  " << Result << endl;
        X += DeltaX;
    }

    system("pause");
}
double LogFunction(double x)
{
    return log((1 + x) / (1 - x));
}
double SumRows(double x, double Eps)
{

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=20; i++)
    {
        sum += 2 * (pow(x, 2 * i - 1) / (2 * i - 1));
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: В SumRows sum должна быть double

Comment: `X на [-1;1]` - вообще-то `X на ]-1;1[`

Comment: А почему так, если это область определения и она в cout записана?

Comment: Потому что при x=-1 и x=1 функция не определена. Область определения - `-1 < x < 1` - со строгим неравенством...

Comment: Понял, ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то лучше бы написать вот так:

```
double SumRows(double x, double eps)
{
    double sum = x, term = x;
    x = x*x;
    for(int i = 3; fabs(x)/i > eps; i+=2) sum += (term *= x)/i;
    return 2*sum;
}
```

А, да! рекурсивно -

```
double Recurs(double x, double eps, double term = 0, int i = 1)
{
    if (i == 1)
    {
        term = x;
    }
    else if (fabs(term)/i < eps) return 2*term/i;
    return 2*term/i + Recurs(x,eps,term*x*x,i+2);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Большое спасибо за ответ.